# How to write an asyncio function that combines the output of method in single variable?

Tags: python, concurrency, python-asyncio

So, I have been reading on asyncio. Consider the following example:

```
def f(i):
    return i
```

Now, for the above function, if I want to loop from 1 to 10 to get an output. I can do
`[f(i) for i in range(10)]`. Using asyncio gather, we can do:
`asyncio.gather(*[f(i) for i in range(10)])` Both of them return a list to me.
But say, I want to aggregate the values to get the sum. ie

```
sum=0
for i in range(10):
    sum+=f(i)
```

Is there some way to do this in asyncio?

Comment: Can you post what you've tried as far as asyncio related code goes? Also, if you have several functions that await to some value, is there a reason you can't just sum each result from `asyncio.gather`?

Comment: The only way I could do that is by looping through each result in the sum for asyncio gather result. But, the total number of loops is really high as I have to loop through a big number of values. Secondly, in my case the function `f` is complicated, and instead of the variable `sum`, there is a different computation that is supposed to happen. So, as in normal looping where I can pass a variable to be updated, is there a way to do so in `asyncio.gather`, instead of looping later on in all the values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [`asyncio.as_completed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.as_completed):

```
sum = 0
for next_result in asyncio.as_completed([f(i) for i in range(10)]):
    sum += await next_result
```